# Running Kubernetes locally on M1 Mac

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, microk8s, apple-silicon

I'm looking to see if it's currently possible to run Kubernetes locally on a 2020 M1 MacBook air.

The environment I need is relatively simple, just for going through some tutorials. As an example, this [operator-sdk guide](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/).

So far I've tried `microk8s` and `minikube`, as they're tools I've used before on other machines.

For both of these, I've installed them using `brew` after opening the terminal app "with Rosetta 2"
(i.e like [this](https://doesitarm.com/app/homebrew/benchmarks/#rU-fa0sbCGs)). My progress is then:

**Minikube**

When I run `minikube start --driver=docker` (having installed the [tech preview of Docker Desktop for M1](https://www.docker.com/blog/download-and-try-the-tech-preview-of-docker-desktop-for-m1/)), an initialization error occurs. It seems to me that this is being tracked here https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9224.

**Microk8s**

`microk8s install` asks to install `multipass`, which then errors with `An error occurred with the instance when trying to start with 'multipass': returned exit code 2. Ensure that 'multipass' is setup correctly and try again.`. Multipass shows a `microk8s-vm` stuck in starting. I think this may relate to this issue https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/1857.

I'm aware I'd probably be better chasing up those issues for help on these particular errors. What would be great is any general advice on if it's currently possible/advisable to setup a basic Kubernetes env for playing with on an M1 mac. I'm not experienced with the underlying technologies here, so any additional context is welcome. :)

If anyone has suggestions for practising Kubernetes, alternative to setting up a local cluster, I'd also appreciate them. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, it is usually good to have Docker when working with containers. Docker now has a [Tech Preview of Docker for Apple M1 based macs](https://www.docker.com/blog/download-and-try-the-tech-preview-of-docker-desktop-for-m1/).

When you have a workin Docker on your machine, it should also work to use [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) - a way to run Kubernetes on Docker containers.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have the Docker Tech Preview installed. Kind initially returned an error for me on `create cluster`, but using the image suggested [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/166#issuecomment-744417522) I was able to create a cluster. Following that thread it sounds like built-in support is on its way.

Comment: @James Cockbain, are you able to run Kubernetes clusters using Kind in docker preview for apple silicon?

Comment: @KarthikaiselvanR - yes, I was able to create a cluster using the image linked above ( `kind create cluster --image rossgeorgiev/kind-node-arm64:v1.20.0`) with the Docker Tech Preview running. I've used that cluster for the operator-sdk tutorial I mentioned in the question, plus some examples from the kubernetes.io docs. Nothing heavy-duty, but has been absolutely fine for me for those.

Comment: @JamesCockbain, Thanks for your info. Cheers!

Comment: So how do I connect to cluster? I was able to run `skaffold dev` and services were working but I couldn't connect to them with Ingress Nginx

Comment: @AndreyGritsay, Please have a look at [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9224#issuecomment-776189649)

Comment: @KarthikaiselvanR I couldn't run minikubes for some reason, though yesterday Docker was updated with Kubernetes support!

Comment: @KarthikaiselvanR I have problems with the new updated version, too, because Kubernetes still stuck at starting progress. Are you using that built-in Kubernetes in docker desktop?

Comment: @SayJeyHi I have that problem with the built-in Kubernetes on Docker Desktop for m1 too. Only way I could find to get out of the "Kubernetes is starting" state was to do "Reset to factory defaults" from troubleshooting menu. I've now moved on from Kind to Minikube following the thread from above, and is working fine for me. Specifically, I followed the instruction in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9224#issuecomment-772606796) video.

Comment: @JamesCockbain, why you didn't use kind? was there any problems with it?

Comment: @SayJeyHi - sorry I could have worded that better! I still have Kind installed and works fine, but having got Minikube working yesterday I've been trying that out. I was able to to [connect to a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/) on the cluster externally using Minikube - which is something I haven't managed with Kind. Apart from that, I'm not in a position yet to give a preference.

Comment: This guy got kubernetes working, note that I installed the preview of docker beforehand: https://jimmyb.ninja/post/1609779188

Comment: How is it going by 2nd of September 2021. Could anyone please update ?

Comment: I'm trying this tut https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/ with minikube on an M1 Mac mini and it doesn't create the backend pods - they just crash or error. I've had consistent problems with creating services - targetPorts don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Update (Jan 2022): I noticed that microk8s docs have published a [tutorial for m1 installs](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/installing-microk8s-on-apple-m1-silicon#1-installation). I followed this and it works fine on my machine now.

Additionally, I can also now setup a cluster on Minikube by following the instructions in the [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)  with `ARM64` as my architecture.