# zsh: bad CPU type in executable: kubectl (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: macos, kubernetes, zsh, kubectl

I am trying to install Kubernetes in Mac. I followed these instructions - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/ (for MacOs)

Followed all the 5 steps mentioned in that link

```
1. curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl"

2.curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl.sha256"

echo "$(<kubectl.sha256)  kubectl" | shasum -a 256 --check 

output: kubectl: OK

3. chmod +x ./kubectl

4. sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl && \
sudo chown root: /usr/local/bin/kubectl

5. kubectl version --client
```

Apparently, when I executed this kubectl version --client

`zsh: bad CPU type in executable: kubectl`

I tried to switch the shell from zsh to sh, bash but nothing helped

Comment: Any chance you're running on an M1 mac?

Comment: The [Homebrew `kumernetes-cli` package](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/kubernetes-cli#default) also might be a reasonable installation path.

Comment: @larsks yes, its M1 Mac

Comment: @larsks Is this an issue with M1 Mac?

Comment: @VJohn it looks like someone had similar issue like yours. Please take a look here: https://jimmyb.ninja/

Answer (score 3):

For Mac M1 - install Rosetta `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Working on my M1 Big Sur 11.5.1

For more info , have a look on this link [Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861)

Check this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable?newreg=943f42fc6a254d34bb2729742d135920)

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to download a version of `kubectl` for the `darmin/amd64` architecture. "Darwin" means, effectively, MacOS, and `amd64` refers to Intel and AMD 64-bit processors.

You have an M1 Mac, which famously is built [around an ARM processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1), unlike the rest of Apple's machines.

You would need to find `kubectl` built for `darwin/arm64`. As @DavidMaze suggested, you may be able to obtain that by installing the `kubernetes-cli` package via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864009/running-kubernetes-locally-on-m1-mac

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem. Resolved by following steps:

- rm /usr/local/bin/kubectl
- brew install kubectl

Now check command:

- kubectl version --client

  you will get output something like this:

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21",
> GitVersion:"v1.21.2",
> GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7",
> GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:52:14Z",
> GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}

Answer (score 0):

The problem can have two reasons:
1- you either have a mac book with an apple silicon processor which is not supported by the app you start (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211814)
2- you start a i386 executable in a 64bit operating system

**Solution**:
1- you should install rosetta that makes this integration
2- you should check if the app is really developed for a i386 system or not. If so install the 64bit version

For me the problem was the 32bit / 64bit mismatch. To see if the app you are starting has a i386 or not you can run:

```
find `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"` -perm +1111 -exec file {} \; | grep i386
```

installing the 64bit version solved my issue.